# Adding a Value to the Neighbor Cell

Tags: excel, vba, filter, max, addition

I've written a macro about first filtering some columns, finding the maximum visible value in another column, adding it an another cell and paint it. It works fine.

But I must add the same number to the neighbor cell (right one in the same row) too.

For example suppose that the the cell will the highest value is C12. I want to add ("Sheet2").Range("A1") to C12 and D12. Code can add that value to C12. I want help for the other one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just offset ss by 1 column, and add y to the offset cell.

```
If ss.Value = mx Then
    ss.Value = ss.Value + y
    ss.offset(0, 1).value = ss.offset(0, 1).value + y
    ss.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You can use `offset` again to set the color index of the cell, if you need to.

For information on the `offset` property please see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

Comment: That does it.  Thanks.

    ss.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + y